# Rails/ActiveRecord: has_one, belongs_to and before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having trouble figuring out how best to model my data. I have the following two models in my Rails application:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :active_bar, :class_name => 'Bar'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :active_bar

  before_create do |f|
    f.active_bar.foo = f

    # Causes stack overflow!
    f.active_bar.save!
  end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

test 'create with nested attributes' do
  f = Foo.create!(:name => 'foo-name', :active_bar_attributes => {:name => 'bar-name'})
  assert_equal 'foo-name', f.name
  assert_equal 'bar-name', f.active_bar.name
  assert_equal f, f.active_bar.foo

  f_id = f.to_param

  retrieved_f = Foo.find_by_id!(f_id)
  assert_equal retrieved_f, retrieved_f.active_bar.foo
end
```

What you probably think is strange is the reflexive `belongs_to` relationship I'm attempting to model. My plan is that, eventually, `Foo` will have many instances of `Bar` while one instance will be considered "active". Thus I'm using `active_bar` to refer to this active instance. The problem with this code is that I need to set the `foo` property in `Bar` back to the parent `Foo` instance and I can't figure out the best place to do it (the `save!` call in `before_create` ends up being recursive and overflowing the stack) or even if this is the cleanest way to model this type of relationship.

Essentially I'm attempting to model a user (equivalent to `Foo`) who has multiple e-mail addresses (equivalent to `Bar`) with one of the e-mail addresses marked as the user's primary address.

Any advice?

Comment: I think I'll move the code in `before_create` into `after_create` instead. That seems to work. I'm still not completely happy with the relationships as modelled, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to respond in terms of User and EmailAddress if that's okay with you ;)

In your User model should really be `has_many :email_addresses`, `has_one :active_email, :class_name => 'EmailAddress'` and, as you correctly identified, `accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_addresses`

The EmailAddress model should then, of course, have `belongs_to :User`.

Aside from these, I think you are over-thinking things. In the form to create a user, then, allow them to enter as many email addresses as they want and either have them put their "active" email first, or have some sort of toggle to denote which email address is their primary address.

Edit: As far as the before_create statement, I think it only needs to be a simple validation that a primary email address has been given/marked (if it is necessary that they specify an email address in the first place).

If this doesn't fulfull what functionality you need, please comment. I'll try and help more.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! When I get a chance I'll try it out.

-Richard

Comment: I have the same issue. Where the actual value for `active_email_id` stored? Shouldn't `has_one` be `belongs_to` in rails terms - though looks bad in english.